TLS CA certificate fail in data flow job
I have created custom data flow templates with Python Apache beam. In template logic, I am calling rest api with Python requests. I want to authenticate the api call with CA certificate but in dataflow job I am getting below error.

Could not find Suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, Invalid path: /extra_files/cert.pem

I have saved cert.pem in GCP bucket and trying to access this with
--extraFilesToStage:gs://bucket/cert.pem
Req code is:
Resp = requests.get(url, verify='/extra_files/cert.pem', beaders=headers, timeout=120)

what is wrong here ?

Did you download the GCS file to a local file?

No I have not downloaded it. I have tried with storing the .pem certificate in folder or with gsutil path from bucket. It says invalid path.

Looking at this previous question it appears to be some installation and dependencies issues, Can you try some of the solution posted here, if applicable?

You need to allow pip to reference to the correct certificate. check >the certificate first;

python -c "import certifi; print(certifi.where())"


Then first test it manually;

pip install -r requirements.txt --cert=<the above certificate path>


If that works fine, then update this path on pip.conf file located at >$HOME/.pip/pip.conf (or %APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini on Windows). e.g.

[global]
cert = /usr/local/share/ca-certificate/mycert.crt

